# A word to describe works of fiction/entertainment that seeks to indirectly educate its audience on some topic(s)

Tags: single-word-requests

There's a specific, somewhat uncommon word I have in mind.  I came across it some time ago, but I can't remember it and can't find it back.  It perfectly, succinctly represents what I'm about to describe.  Also, it's **not** *edutainment*.

The word is one you would use to describe a novel/game/movie/whatever which, as an accessory to its primary goal of entertaining the audience, also seeks to educate the audience about specific topics.

For example, imagine a political thriller where the audience comes away with some understanding of the inner workings of the U.S. senate.  Or imagine a work of historical fiction that greatly deepens the audience's understanding of a particular aspect of the Korean War.  Or a novel where the protagonist is a sumo wrestler, and the audience comes to learn a great deal about sumo culture as a byproduct of the storytelling.

Comment: I can picture exactly what you're taking about, but I don't think there's a specific word for it. I did a quick check of TVTropes, [starting at Edutainment](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EdutainmentShow), and came up dry. The best they offer is "informative" or the label "E/I" (educational/informative).

Comment: It's been about a year or two since I encountered the word, but I think there was a Wikipedia article about the word that explained the idea and provided some examples of works that fell into the category.

Comment: @Dan Bron: *... a **quick** check of TVTropes?* Isn't that the [ultimate oxymoron?](http://www.fun-with-words.com/0974504904.html) Or is your browser running some kind of "anti-Tardis" extension? (to prevent time ceasing to exist once you enter the site! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could the word you are looking for be *didactic*?

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/didactic) *didactic*

> a :  designed or intended to teach
>
> b :  intended to convey instruction and information as well as pleasure and entertainment - didactic poetry

Comment: This is pretty good! A little broader than what I think OP is seeking, but helpful. +1.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's the exact one!  My description is slightly different, but that's likely due to my poor memory.  I believe this is the Wikipedia article I mentioned in my other comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Didacticism

Comment: +1 I've never met the sense licensed as 'b'.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the term ***[educational](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/educational)*** with the connotation of:

> ***tending or intended to educate, instruct, or inform:***
>
> - *an educational show on television.*

(Dictionary.com)

Comment: But you wouldn't really call a political thriller which is only incidentally informative an "educational film", would you?

Comment: @DanBron - I'd probably use *educational fiction* in  that case.